# Systemd RootDirectory Option failed

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, chroot

I've written a simple service to try Systemd on my Ubuntu 17.0. When I used the option `RootDirectory`, it failed to start up my service. Here are some details:

```
[Unit]
Description= my service

[Service]
RootDirectory=/home/myname/myservice/
ExecStart=myservice_exec


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=myservice.service
```

The binary file is located on

```
/home/myname/myservice/myservice_exec
```

This is the error I get from journalctl:

```
Failed at step EXEC spawning : No such file or directory
```

Other probable helpful details:

```
>/lib/systemd/systemd --version
systemd 232
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

Does anybody know the reason?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In systemd v232, `ExecStart` must always specify the binary to run using an absolute path. I think that path is relative to the specified root directory, so try this:

```
ExecStart=/myservice_exec
```

Note that unless `myservice_exec` is a hard-linked binary, this will also require a somewhat populated `lib` directory to exist under `/home/myname/myservice/`, and possibly some other files as well.